# Saltos de linea en html

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un formulario común que envía datos a firebase.
En un `textarea` se escribe texto, sabemos que con la tecla `enter` se generan saltos de linea.

Al enviar esta información en firebase se guarda cómo un string pero...

Al mostrarlos en un `p` esos saltos de linea, intenté con `pre` y los saltos de linea sí se generan pero se salen de sus contenedores

Esto es lo que intenté

```html
<div style="background:red">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit praesent nibh in condimentum risus, vehicula mus pretium facilisi tortor mi facilisis sapien mollis odio blandit ridiculus, accumsan enim per egestas fringilla montes maecenas hac purus integer arcu.
    Placerat magnis maecenas dictum sapien eros congue, ligula ullamcorper mollis sagittis vehicula, aliquam sociis luctus lobortis nisi. |Eu ante pharetra tellus maecenas tincidunt ultrices inceptos quis vestibulum porta consequat congue, eros rhoncus
    magnis justo potenti aliquam neque mus curabitur sem.
  </p>
</div>

<div style="background:red">
  <pre>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit praesent nibh in condimentum risus, vehicula mus pretium facilisi tortor mi facilisis sapien mollis odio blandit ridiculus, accumsan enim per egestas fringilla montes maecenas hac purus integer arcu.
    
    Placerat magnis maecenas dictum sapien eros congue, ligula ullamcorper mollis sagittis vehicula, aliquam sociis luctus lobortis nisi. |Eu ante pharetra tellus maecenas tincidunt ultrices inceptos quis vestibulum porta consequat congue, eros rhoncus
    
    magnis justo potenti aliquam neque mus curabitur sem.
  </pre>
</div>
```

Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo mostrar los saltos de linea ?

Comment: reemplazar los saltos de línea con `<br>` para mostrarlos es una opción. que lenguaje usas para armar el html?

Comment: uso javascript, pero poner los `<br>` manualmente no es lo ideal pues lo que estoy desarrollando no es manejado por personas con conocimientos de html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En javascript es `str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');` si pones tu código lo integramos y ya queda como respuesta a futuros usuarios

Por ejemplo:

```js
str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit praesent nibh in condimentum risus, vehicula mus pretium facilisi tortor mi facilisis sapien mollis odio blandit ridiculus, accumsan enim per egestas fringilla montes maecenas hac purus integer arcu.\nPlacerat magnis maecenas dictum sapien eros congue, ligula ullamcorper mollis sagittis vehicula, aliquam sociis luctus lobortis nisi. \r\nEu ante pharetra tellus maecenas tincidunt ultrices inceptos quis vestibulum porta consequat congue, eros rhoncus\nmagnis justo potenti aliquam neque mus curabitur sem.";

document.getElementById('sinreemplazar').innerHTML = str;

str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');

document.getElementById('conreemplazo').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<p id="sinreemplazar">

</p>

<p id="conreemplazo">

</p>
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/784547/1423096

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="background:red">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit praesent nibh in condimentum risus, vehicula mus pretium facilisi tortor mi facilisis sapien mollis odio blandit ridiculus, accumsan enim per egestas fringilla montes maecenas hac purus integer arcu.<br/>
    Placerat magnis maecenas dictum sapien eros congue, ligula ullamcorper mollis sagittis vehicula, aliquam sociis luctus lobortis nisi.<br />|Eu ante pharetra tellus maecenas tincidunt ultrices inceptos quis vestibulum porta consequat congue, eros rhoncus
    magnis justo potenti aliquam neque mus curabitur sem.
  </p>
</div>

<div style="background:red">
  <pre>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit praesent nibh in condimentum risus, vehicula mus pretium facilisi tortor mi facilisis sapien mollis odio blandit ridiculus, accumsan enim per egestas fringilla montes maecenas hac purus integer arcu.
    
    Placerat magnis maecenas dictum sapien eros congue, ligula ullamcorper mollis sagittis vehicula, aliquam sociis luctus lobortis nisi. |Eu ante pharetra tellus maecenas tincidunt ultrices inceptos quis vestibulum porta consequat congue, eros rhoncus
    
    magnis justo potenti aliquam neque mus curabitur sem.
  </pre>
</div>
```

Solo debes agregar `<br />`

Comment: Eso funciona, pero lo que busco es no incluír html dentro del texto manualmente, esos textos entran desde javascript